# Use of awake and awaken

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say?

> The sound of the alarm woke up Rob. For the first 10 seconds he was confused, but once he was fully awake jumped out of bed and went to take a shower.

Or instead of "awake", should I say "fully awaken"?

Answer (score 3):

***[Awake](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awake)*** is usually, as it is here, used as an adjective, though it can be a verb. On superficial inspection, it seems to be identical in meaning to ***awaken***. Both can be transitive or intransitive, both are often used in the passive voice, and both tend to be used in written English more than spoken English. *Awake* is found largely in its past tense, *awoke*, but not exclusively. Mainly, the pattern of use tends towards differences that are hard to describe.

However, both are used largely in more poetic language. *Wake* and *waken* are more prosaic.

The adjective ***awake***, however, which is what you've used here, is an adjective - and *awaken* is not an adjective, only a verb. You could use its past participle, *awoken* or *awakened* (depending on who you ask), which would be grammatical, but using the adjective *awake* is more idiomatic. So, if you want a verb, you could use *awake*, *awaken*, *wake* or *waken*, but if you want an adjective there's just *awake*, and the others are not alternatives to it.

What you've written is fine in that regard, though I would add a *he* before *jumped* to be good otherwise. You could also get the same effect with commas instead of the extra word.

Answer (score -1):

What you have quoted is grammatical. You can omit 'up' after 'woke' in the first sentence for greater formality; you can omit 'he was' from the second sentence, and I would insert a comma after 'but' and 'fully awake'. "For the first 10 seconds he was confused, but, once fully awake, jumped out of bed and went to take a shower."